Is there any resource/data in mongodb/mongodbatls provider to fetch federated+online archived connection string
Current:
A AWS privatelink service to connect to mongoDB cluster, this private link is created through terraform hashicorp/aws and mongodb/mongodbatlas provider. The connection_string for this link is fetched from mongodbatlas_cluster resource attributes. under private endpoint.
Changes:
Enabled online archived on one of the collection through resource mongodbatlas_online_archive provided by provider, also one federated + online archived private link is also created through the resource mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_service_data_federation_online_archive.
Everything is showing in UI, but new federated+online archived connection string is not listed in mongodbatlas_cluster output attributes.
Is there any other resource that will output this url?
